# Changing common project library values from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I have a project with a common bash file for variables. Is there a way for scripts to change these?

A sample action script:

```bsh
$ cat sampleaction.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Source variables
. commonlibrary

# Do action according to mode
case $MODE in 
    idle)
        #do nothing
    active)
        #do something
```

`$MODE` exists in a common file and is only checked at the launch of each individual action script. I would like this variable to be set by the setup bash script if it contains a flag, eg. `--active`.

The setup script:

```bsh
cat initaction.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Source variables
. commonlibrary

# Check flags
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do 
    case $1 in
        --active)
            shift;
            MODE=active;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What is that common file you're talking about? How is it checked at launch? What is the init file you're talking about?

Comment: @Fanatique Thanks! The common file is a simple bash file used as a variable library, where in this case it holds `MODE=idle`. At launch, the init bash file sources the common file `. commonlibrary` and assigns a different value to it if it contains an `--active` flag. The problem is that this is only local and unrelated action scripts can only use the default value in `commonlibrary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the variable in the common file by just echoing the new values into that file:

```
echo "MODE=active" > commonlibrary
```

An example with your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
. commonlibrary

case $MODE in 
    idle)
        #do nothing
    active)
        echo "MODE=newmode" > commonlibrary
```

Now, if you had more than one variable in that file, this would pose a problem. You would need to get every variable first and then build all the new values and add them to the file. There are many ways to do that, you can either research about it or think of your own way.